# WebClient.CancelAsync — File still downloading

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, webclient

I'm trying to create a Web API using Asp.NET Core that exposes routes to start and cancel long downloads of large files. The server should be able to handle multiple downloads at the same time.

- The download is performed using `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync` in order to have a short response time and returning a `downloadId` for later use. The instance of the WebClient is stored as value in a static dictionary whose corresponding `key` is of naturally the `downloadId`.
- The download should be canceled using `WebClient.CancelAsync` on the instance of the client retrieved by accessing the value of the dictionary corresponding to the `downloadId` key.

The following code works perfectly when the download reaches its completion without being canceled; the AsyncCompletedEventHandler (`OnDownloadFileCompleted` in that case) is properly invoked.

**PROBLEM**: When invoking `WebClient.CancelAsync`, the file keeps on downloading and `OnDownloadFileCompleted` is not invoked right away. The WebClient seems to wait until the download finishes before invoking the handler. In both case however, the property `AsyncCompletedEventArgs.Canceled` is properly set (e.g to `true` if `WebClient.CancelAsync` was indeed invoked.

- Am I missing something?
- Is there a better/smarter pattern to handle multiple downloads in a WebAPI?

Any help would much appreciated!

**DownloadController.cs**

```
[Route ("api/download")]
public class DownloadController {

    private readonly DownloadService service;

    public DownloadController (DownloadService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    [Route ("start")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Start ([FromForm] string fileUrl) => this.service.StartDownload (fileUrl);

    [Route ("cancel")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void Cancel ([FromForm] string downloadId) => this.service.CancelDownload (downloadId);
}
```

**DownloadService.cs**

```
public class DownloadService {
    public string DOWNLOAD_FOLDER { get => "C:\\tmp"; }
    public static Dictionary<string, WebClient> DownloadClients = new Dictionary<string, WebClient> ();

    public string StartDownload (string fileUrl) {
        var downloadId = Guid.NewGuid ().ToString ("N");
        DownloadClients[downloadId] = new WebClient ();
        DownloadClients[downloadId].DownloadFileCompleted += OnDownloadFileCompleted;
        DownloadClients[downloadId].DownloadFileAsync (new Uri (fileUrl), Path.Combine (DOWNLOAD_FOLDER, downloadId), downloadId);
        return downloadId;
    }

    public void CancelDownload (string downloadId) {
        if (DownloadClients.TryGetValue (downloadId, out WebClient client)) {
            client.CancelAsync ();
        }
    }

    private void OnDownloadFileCompleted (object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) {
        var downloadId = e.UserState.ToString ();
        if (!e.Cancelled) {
            Debug.WriteLine ("Completed");
        } else {
            Debug.WriteLine ("Cancelled"); //will only be reached when the file finishes downloading
        }

        if (DownloadClients.ContainsKey (downloadId)) {
            DownloadClients[downloadId].Dispose ();
            DownloadClients.Remove (downloadId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using `HttpClient` instead.

Comment: Side note - consider using ConcurrentDictionary, since your code is not safe now and might throw surprising errors when multiple users will use it.

Comment: @Evk, thanks for the advice. My main problem was not concurrency but indeed, I should use it

Comment: Your code prints `Cancelled` if `e.Cancelled` is `false`.

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev, my bad! I edited the question, thanks

Comment: @PierreRoudaut, are you sure `client.CancelAsync ();` is invoking? Are you sure that for each request you have one service instance?

Comment: @YuryKerbitskov, I'm sure the `client.CancelAsync` is invoked: when the file finally finishes to download the property `e.Canceled` is set to true. The dictionary is static, so shared among any instance of the service.

Comment: Can you measure actual time that passes between `client.CancelAsync()` and `OnDownloadFileCompleted()`? You can use `Stopwatch` or `DateTime`.

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev, the time between `client.CancelAsync()` invokation and `OnDownloadFileCompleted` depends on the speed and size of the download. The `WebClient` will wait until the download finishes to invoke `OnDownloadFileCompleted`. I am certain of that as I was checking the growing size of the file on the filesystem; when the size stopped growing, the handler was then fired.

Comment: I'd personally just use good old HttpWebRequest. A little bit more code but at least you control everything and can certainly cancel when necessary.

Comment: What I see after fixing `DownloadController` routes and constructor is cancellation POST request blocked by ASP.NET, probably because of some session state usage. In my Web API instance cancellation POST request can be processed only after download is finished. If it's not the case in your Web API instance please provide [minimum, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to replicate what you saw: `CancelAsync` does not actually cancel the download.

Using `HttpClient`, you can get the stream and save it to a file using `CopyToAsync`, accepts a `CancellationToken`. Cancelling the token stops the download immediately.

Here is the `DownloadService` class that I modified to use `HttpClient`.

```
public class DownloadService {
    public string DOWNLOAD_FOLDER {
        get => "C:\\tmp";
    }

    public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Download> Downloads = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Download>();

    public async Task<string> StartDownload(string fileUrl) {
        var downloadId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        Downloads[downloadId] = new Download(fileUrl);
        await Downloads[downloadId].Start(Path.Combine(DOWNLOAD_FOLDER, downloadId));

        return downloadId;
    }

    public void CancelDownload(string downloadId) {
        if (Downloads.TryRemove(downloadId, out var download)) {
            download.Cancel();
        }
    }
```

This uses a `Download` class that looks like this:

```
public class Download {
    private static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
    private readonly string _fileUrl;

    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private Task _copyTask;
    private Stream _responseStream;
    private Stream _fileStream;

    public Download(string fileUrl) {
        _fileUrl = fileUrl;
    }

    public async Task Start(string saveTo) {
        var response = await Client.GetAsync(_fileUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        _responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        _fileStream = File.Create(saveTo);
        _copyTask = _responseStream.CopyToAsync(_fileStream, 81920, _tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled) return;
            _responseStream.Dispose();
            _fileStream.Dispose();
        });
    }

    public void Cancel() {
        _tokenSource.Cancel();
        _responseStream.Dispose();
        _fileStream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You will still have some work to do to remove successfully-completed downloads from your `Downloads` list, but I'll leave that with you.

Comment: Using HttpClient isn't convoluted but *this* code is. Why are you using `ContinueWith` instead of `async/await`? Why use all those dictionaries? Finally, the code doesn't cancel the *actual* downloading operation, which is the `CopyTo` operation inside `ReadAsFileAsync`

Comment: He seems to want the API request to finish and return the `downloadId` and have the download complete in the background. So using `await` isn't appropriate. You need the `Dictionary` to keep a reference to the download so when a cancel request hits the API, it can look up the `downloadId` and cancel it. The actual downloading happens in the `GetAsync` task, which is what gets cancelled. The `ContinueWith` doesn't even start until the download is complete.

Comment: `await` does prevent sending the `downloadId` to the API client before the download completes, which is undesirable. That article you linked to only talks about how you should reuse `HttpClient`, which is what my code is already doing.

Comment: `await` doesn't prevent the job from running in the background. You wouldn't need the dictionary if the cancellation source was created outside the function, as is its typical usage.

Comment: If you can link to something that shows how to save directly to a file without saving to memory first (while still allowing use of a `CancellationToken`) then that would be helpful.

Comment: I'm looking for the article that shows how to *avoid* downloading everything in memory, the short version is *don't*, return as soon as you get the headers. Otherwise you *can't* cancel until the entire file returns - the very same problem WebClient has

Comment: I've changed my answer so it doesn't save it entirely to memory first. I followed this: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/efficiently-streaming-large-http-responses-with-httpclient

Comment: @GabrielLuci, thank you so much! 
I tested it with multiple downloads at the same time, your solution works like a charm ! 
I'm still a bit confused about why `DownloadService.StartDownload` needs to `await` the `Download.Start` considering it is executed in the background but I might miss some practice with async/await...

Comment: The `Download.Start` method has to await a couple things (like getting the HTTP headers from the downloaded file) before it returns, which means it has to be an async method.