# How to STOP a WebClient download

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

When downloading data using

```
byte[] data = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(uri);
```

or any other `async` method, is there some way to ***stop*** the download? I don't want to just ignore the result. I want to abort the download which can be expensive on mobile, and can slow down an alternative download if the user has cancelled it in favor of a different download.

I tried

```
webClient.CancelAsync();
```

but it seems to just raise a `TaskCanceledException` *after* the download is completed. I see this by wrapping the awaited download in a try-catch block. The catch is called a long time after the `CancelAsync()` is.

Comment: Please have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187976/webclient-cancelasync-file-still-downloading

Comment: @FrancoFusaro Thanks. You can transform that into an answer. Though I'm still waiting to see if anyone comes up with a simpler way.

Comment: @FrancoFusaro I'll also add that according to the links in [this answer on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/69954) a single HttpClient must be used for the whole application, and that then leads to other problems (such as stale DNS).

Comment: @ispiro it's not **must**, it's recommended. All in all, cancelling the download is a common problem in .Net with no simple solution. You may try to partially download it, or download it to file (as in linked answer), but there is no magic way to tell unmanaged code that it needs to stop.

Comment: @VMAtm It's recommended for a good reason - [here's a post](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) about how bad it can get if you create new ones every time. But point taken - there seems to be no magical solution.

Answer (score -2):

You can continu using **CancelAsync()**, but you need to verify that the file is not canceled inside the *DownloadFileCompleted event*

```
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
      if (e.Cancelled)
      {
          //cleanup delete partial file
          Client.Dispose();                    
          return;
      } 
      else 
      {/* the file is not cancelled, do what you need with it here, no TaskCanceledException would occure */}
 }
```